# Значение из строки n, столбца m DataGrid записать в переменную

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть DataGrid, в одном из столбцов всегда хранится одно и то же числовое значение. Как это самое значение записать в переменную типа int?
Знаю, что в WinForms с DataGridView делается так:

```
String s = dataGridView1[1, 2].Value.ToString();
```

А как это делается в WPF c DataGrid - не знаю.
 
DataGrid:

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="AbitSpecDG" x:FieldModifier="public" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="600" Width="1150" IsReadOnly="True" 
                              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Background="{x:Null}" LoadingRow="AbitSpecDG_LoadingRow" HeadersVisibility="All">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="ID Абитуриента" Binding="{Binding id_abit}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="ID Специальности" Binding="{Binding id_spec}"/>
    
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Фамилия" Binding="{Binding abit.MName}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding abit.Name}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Отчество" Binding="{Binding abit.LName}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Ср. балл" Binding="{Binding abit.AvgMark}"/>
    
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Специальность" Binding="{Binding specialty.Name}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Кол-во мест" Binding="{Binding specialty.NumberOfSeats}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Заполнение DataGrid:

```
  abit_spec newAbSpec = new abit_spec()
                        {
                            id_abit = Convert.ToInt32(tb_IDabit.Text),
                            id_spec = Convert.ToInt32(tb_IDspec.Text),
                        };
                        db.abit_spec.Add(newAbSpec);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        AbSpec.dataGrid.ItemsSource = db.abit_spec.ToList();
```

Comment: А в WPF используют биндинги `Binding`. Если покажете ваш xaml и код, как вы наполняете `DaraGrid`, я покажу вам как правильно сделать в WPF. В WPF напрямую с контролами почти никто не работает, поэтому я хоть и понимаю, что вы хотите узнать, но никогда не делал этого, хотя у меня много всяких разных `DataGrid` в проектах. А в winforms это делается так `dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value.ToString()`.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Если с контролами на прямую не работают, то что тогда? MVVM?

Comment: Да, MVVM, но опять же MVVM - это не обязательно, речь идет о методике взаимодействия с `DataGrid` в `WPF`. И методика в том, что с `DataGrid` взаимодействовать не нужно, а сама `DataGrid` должна взаимодействовать с данными. Сейчас напишу пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел способ. Дело в том, что в `DataGrid` за представление ячейки отвечает контрол соответствующего типа. Например для `DataGridTextColumn` это `TextBlock`.

А получить его значение можно таким образом:

```csharp
TextBlock x = dataGrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(dataGrid.Items[1]) as TextBlock;
string s = x?.Text;
```

Но еще раз замечу, что так в WPF никто не делает.

А делают немного иначе, объясню на простом примере. Покажу без MVVM, просто с биндингами.

---

#### Часть 1. Привязка данных

1. Создать класс данных (у вас наверное такой есть)

```csharp
public class MyData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

2. Задать `DataContext` для окна. Если вы не используете MVVM, то проще всего это сделать в конструкторе окна. Это позволит легко и просто пользоваться биндингами в xaml

```csharp
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

3. Создать коллекцию. Если хочется, чтобы `DataGrid` сама обновлялась, когда в коллекцию добавляются элементы, или удаляются из нее, то лучше использовать `ObservableCollection`.

```csharp
public ObservableCollection<MyData> MyCollection { get; set; }
```

Можно внести в нее какие-нибудь тестовые данные. Работать с коллекцией можно точно так же как с `List`.

```csharp
MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyData>
{
    new MyData{FirstName="Василий", LastName="Пупкин"},
    new MyData{FirstName="Иван", LastName="Иванов"}
};
```

4. И прибиндиться к этой коллекции в xaml

```xaml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="Имя"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Фамилия"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Чтобы получить элемент коллекции, расположенный во второй колонке и второй строке, можно просто обратиться к данным, так как `DataGrid` будет обновлять данные автоматически.

```csharp
string s = MyCollection[1].LastName;
```

---

#### Часть 2. Двухстороннее обновление данных

Есть такой интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`, практически все контролы в WPF поддерживают событие `PropertyChanged`, если вызвать которое при использовании `Binding`, то контрол сам себя обновит при обновлении данных.

Вот вам класс помощник, унаследовав который можно сделать так, чтобы когда вы обновляете данные, ячейки таблицы обновлялись сами, а наоборот это уже происходит в результате действий из первой части.

Просто добавьте этот класс отдельно в решение (не внутрь класса Window).

```csharp
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Теперь просто остается унаследовать этот класс и модифицировать свойства класса данных следующим образом.

```csahrp
public class MyData : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;

    public string FirstName 
    {
        get => _firstName;
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // сообщить всем биндингам, которые привязаны сюда о том, что данные поменялись
        }
    }
    public string LastName 
    {
        get => _lastName; 
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

А теперь становится доступен следующий трюк:

```csharp
MyCollection[1].LastName = "Петров";
```

В результате выполнения этого кода, содержимое ячейки в `DataGrid` поменяется само.

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо! Ни один из моих преподов мне бы так не разжевал, как это сделали вы.

Comment: @GeloS домашнее задание: реализуйте `INotifyPropertyChanged` для `MyCollection`. Вы же знаете, что нельзя наследоваться от двух классов одновременно, и класс окна уже наследует `Window`. Но можно выкрутиться и у наследовать интерфейс напрямую, дальше сами. :)

Comment: @GeloS А зачем реализовывать для `MyCollection` - это для того, что если в процессе работы программы вы ее пересоздадите `new ObservableCollection<MyData>...`, то `DataGrid` этого не заметит. Присваивать `ItemsSource` некрасиво, когда вы уже умеете использовать `Binding`, поэтому вариант один: `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Ценный материал, даром не пропадёт. Ещё раз спасибо)

Comment: @GeloS еще почитайте про [Поля](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) и [Свойства](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). И обратите внимание, что поля я называю с маленькой буквы и подчеркиванием впереди, а свойства с большой и без. А локальные переменные я называю просто с маленькой и без подчеркивания. Я не использую подчеркивания в середине, использую заглавные буквы в середине вместо этого. В результате у меня нет конфликтов имён, никогда. Это кстати понятный многим стандарт.