# Конветрирование DataGrid в PDF с помощью iTextSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, itextsharp

Пытаюсь конвертировать DataGrid в PDF файл не используя MVVM, работая на прямую с контролами:

```
                    //Объект документа пдф
                    Document doc = new Document();
                    //Создаем объект записи пдф-документа в файл
                    string folderPath = "C:\\PDFs\\";
                    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
                    }
                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(folderPath + "Рейтинг.pdf", FileMode.Create));
                    //Открываем документ
                    doc.Open();
                    //Определение шрифта 
                    BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\times.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                    Font font = new Font(baseFont, Font.DEFAULTSIZE, Font.NORMAL);
                    //Создаем объект таблицы и передаем в нее число столбцов таблицы
                    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(AbitSpecDG.Columns.Count);               
                    //Добавим в таблицу общий заголовок
                    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Рейтинг по специальности " + AbitSpecDG.Columns[6].GetCellContent(AbitSpecDG.Items[1]).ToString(), font));
                    cell.Colspan = AbitSpecDG.Columns.Count;
                    cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    //Убираем границу первой ячейки
                    cell.Border = 0;
                    table.AddCell(cell);

                        //Сначала добавляем заголовки таблицы
                        for (int j = 0; j < AbitSpecDG.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                               cell  = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(AbitSpecDG.Columns[j].Header.ToString(), font));
                                cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
                            table.AddCell(cell);
                        } 
                        //Добавляем все остальные ячейки
                        for (int j = 0; j < AbitSpecDG.Items.Count; j++)
                        {
                            for (int k = 0; k < AbitSpecDG.Columns.Count; k++)
                            {
                                table.AddCell(new Phrase(AbitSpecDG.Items[j].ToString(), font));
                            }
                        }
                        //Добавляем таблицу в документ
                        doc.Add(table);             
                    //Закрываем документ
                    doc.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Pdf-документ сохранен");
```

На выходе получаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему то только заголовки полей конвертируются нормально.А что с остальными не так, я не понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `AbitSpecDG.Items[j].ToString()` - это то что вы видите в PDF.

```cs
table.AddCell(new Phrase(AbitSpecDG.Items[j].ToString(), font));
```

замените на

```
table.AddCell(new Phrase((AbitSpecDG.Columns[k].GetCellContent(AbitSpecDG.Items[j]) as TextBlock)?.Text ?? "", font));
```

Больше информации [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1141908/%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-n-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%b0-m-datagrid-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e/1141941#1141941).

---

Как добавить колонку с нумерацией строк

Вот это

```cs
new PdfPTable(AbitSpecDG.Columns.Count);
```

Поменяйте на это

```
new PdfPTable(AbitSpecDG.Columns.Count + 1);
```

Потом вот так

```cs
//Сначала добавляем заголовки таблицы
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("№", font));
cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
table.AddCell(cell);
for (int j = 0; j < AbitSpecDG.Columns.Count; j++)
{
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(AbitSpecDG.Columns[j].Header.ToString(), font));
    cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
    table.AddCell(cell);
}

//Добавляем все остальные ячейки
for (int j = 0; j < AbitSpecDG.Items.Count; j++)
{
    table.AddCell(new Phrase((j+1).ToString(), font));
    for (int k = 0; k < AbitSpecDG.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        table.AddCell(new Phrase((AbitSpecDG.Columns[k].GetCellContent(AbitSpecDG.Items[j]) as TextBlock)?.Text ?? "", font));
    }
}
```

Comment: про TextBlock вылетело из головы, спасибо. В очередной раз выручаете.

Comment: @GeloS добавляйте в начало строки еще одну колонку и пишите туда `j + 1`.

Comment: @GeloS мне казалось, это просто. Дополнил ответ.