# Как из DataGrid заполнить List<>

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Я новичок в программировании, не знаю как из DataGrid заполнить List<> данными из выбранной строки.

```
    private void OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //количество строк
        int row = DG_User.SelectedCells.Count();

       //для данных
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        list.Clear();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            list.Add(DG_User.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
        listTest.ItemsSource = list;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как пробовали? SelectedItem смотрели в DataGrid?

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос, надеюсь что поможете.

Comment: у вас плохой код, как минимум потому что вы используете `Enumerable.Count()` для `IList` вместо св-ва `Count`… face-palm. так же не нужно вызывать `List.Clear` после его создания, т. к. он изначально очищен. думаю, вы поняли

Comment: @return на SO не принято высказывать свое мнение о чужом коде, принято вежливо указывать на ошибки и показывать, как их исправить. У всех разный опыт в написании кода, и это нормально. Если бы я агрился на каждую строчку кода, которую считаю неправильной, я бы разбил рукой себе лицо, но зачем? И ответ, который вы дали, неверен, face-palm. :) `ListBox` надо заполнить  ячейками таблицы в выделенной строке, а не то что вы предложили.

Comment: Автору рекомундую ознакомиться с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141941/373567) ответом, и [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143525/373567) еще пример.

Comment: @aepot аааа… я не понял вопроса. face-palm (ваш (@aepot) от меня) оправдан. щас перепишу. ну и про код. просто мне кажется, что если человек думал что получает `IEnumerable`, а в реальности получил `IList` и для получения количества использует `Count()`, то об этом ему нужно сказать, что у него ошибка