# WPF, datagrid програмно изменить значение ячейки

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-datagrid

У меня есть datagrid:

```xml
<DataGrid    Name="dataGrid1">  
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource NameCellStyle}"    Header="Канал"  Width="0.6*"   IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Channel}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />

                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        
        <DataGridTextColumn  CellStyle="{StaticResource NameCellStyle}" Width="0.4*" Header="Статус"  IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=Status}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Заполнение:

```cs
dataGrid1.Items.Add(new TaskTable()
{
    Channel = "text",
    Status = @"Работает",
});
```

Как изменить определенную ячейку в строке X столбцу Y?

Comment: Вы изначально неверно думаете, не смотрите на то, что вы видите в UI, а смотрите на данные. Вот здесь что вы видите? `dataGrid1.Items.Add(new TaskTable());` Вы видите тут ячейки, столбцы, строки? Нет, так почему вы хотите брать их? У вас простая коллекция, которая содержит классы, так ищите нужный и меняйте ему значение. Также, вы работаете с контролами напрямую, что очень плохо в WPF приложении! Привяжите все, сделайте отдельную коллекцию классов и с ней работайте. Ну а также, вы скорей всего не реализовали INPC, из-за чего ваш UI не обновит данные при изменении их через код.

Comment: Как-то так оно должно выглядеть с привязкой данных `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">` (где `MyItems` - `ObservableCollection<TaskTable>`, а класс `TaskTable` реализует интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`) примеров в поиске по "WPF DataGrid ItemsSource Binding" можно найти очень много, в том числе и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwpf%5D+DataGrid+ItemsSource+Binding). [Готовый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141941/373567)

Comment: @aepot, Решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1141908/%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-n-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%b0-m-datagrid-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e помогло, всем большое спасибо