# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему строка выводится вместе с названием класса

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq, entity

Получаю значение из первого столбца выделенной строки `dataGrid`.

```
var firstSelectedCellContent = 
this.DgridMedicament.Columns[0].GetCellContent(DgridMedicament.SelectedItem);
        
var firstSelectedCell = 
firstSelectedCellContent != null ? firstSelectedCellContent.Parent as DataGridCell : null;
```

Значение выводится вместе с название класса. Как это можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в проекте использую wpf

Comment: А зачем вы у `firstSelectedCellContent ` берете родителя ? ваш контент то находится в firstSelectedCellContent какой это тип? например если это `TextBlock` то приведите к его типу и обр. к свойству `Text`

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225568/wpf-datagrid-get-selected-cell-value),  [или тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148978/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-selectionchanged-getting-cell-value)

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Значение из строки n, столбца m DataGrid записать в переменную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1141908/%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-n-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%b0-m-datagrid-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e)