# C# Xamarin Forms как правильно закрыть страницу если на ней выполняется задача

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

C# Xamarin forms
Подскажите как правильно выйти из страницы если запущена задача.
Пример условного кода.

```
 включаем ActivityIndicator
 bool DownloadDoc = await DownloadDocument("Путь к документу");
                    if (DownloadDoc) //True Успешно
                    {
                     //Код обработки результата
                     Например ListView.Add(Некий результат)//Но контрола уже нет
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      // код выхода
                    }
```

Суть такая. Нажимаем кнопку Скачать из инета документ. Но при этом не дожидаемся процесса скачивания.
Закрываем страницу например кнопкой назад.
Страница закрывается. Задача завершается и приложение просто закрывается.
Самый простой и тупой метод это запретить действия во время скачивания. Светится ActivityIndicator  и пока процесс не завершиться, сменить страницу нельзя. Так и сделано и работает.
Но всетаки, как правильно закрыть страницу и остановить задачу,или проверить что страница закрыта в задаче и не продолжать ничего делать.
Как это правильно обработать?
Самое важное что сам код дожидается выполнения задачи чтобы что-то сделать потом.Например добавить результат в listview. Но он уже уничтожен так как c станицы ушли.
Код условный. Это не значит что там только скачивание. Там могут быть и  просто вычисления.

Спасибо.

Comment: Правильно запускать скачивание фоновой задачей.

Comment: @ Геннадий Про скачивание да. Но я специально написал не только скачивание но там могут быть просто вычисления. И нужно получить результат. И обновить контрол который уже уничтожен. И мне нужно понять как правильно это проверить.

Comment: Задачу вычисления следует запускать с токеном отмены. У страницы есть событие `Disappearing` в обработчике события можно будет отменить задачу с пом. токена отмены.

Comment: @Bulson а вот примерчиком конкретным не тыкните пальцем? хотя направление уже понял куда смотреть.

Comment: @Bulson как прервать задачу я понял. Спасибо. Но эта прерванная задача всеравно выходит и прдолжает код. И если контрол уже уничтожен то получаем вылет. Опять решение в лоб. Сделать маркер закрытия страницы. И перед обращениям к контролам проверять этот флаг. Так проверил работает. Но правильно ли так?

Comment: `Но эта прерванная задача всеравно выходит и прдолжает код.` Если задача была правильно отменена, то все, задача закончила свою работу и ничего не может продолжаться. Может быть проблема с контролами, которые на время задачи были переведены в состояние disabled или спраятаны, надо использовать `finally` блок для возвращения контролам прежнего состояния. А флаг состояния тоже вариант, почему нет? Только флаг тоже лучше отключать в блоке  `finally`.

Comment: @Bulson В общем через токен отмены работает. Задача возвращает false. И нет никакой обработки после false. И работает. Главное после завершонной задачи через токен не обращаться к контролам закрытой страницы. И тогда все норм. Спасибо.

Comment: К контролам по-хорошему вообще не надо обращаться из C# кода, надо использовать `Binding` к данным. Тогда проблема доступа к контролам решится сама собой.

Comment: @aepot  ну так биндинг данных есть. Но например новый список надо присвоить ListView.  например lw1.itemsource = Новый список после задачи.   Ну а данные на странице конечно через binding   ItemsSource="{Binding ldocitems}". Или я что-то тоже и тут  не так делаю?

Comment: `lw1.ItemSource =` - этого не должно быть, нигде, никогда. Вместо этого надо использовать реализацию `INotifyPropertyChanged` для привязываемого свойства. Именно об этом я и говорю, в C# коде с контролами работы быть не должно, совсем никакой. У контролов даже имен не должно быть. Зайдите в XAML, пудаляйте все `x:Name`. И все строчки в C# коде, где вам студия подчеркнет после этого красным - это ваши ошибки, которые надо исправить посредстваом использования биндингов с [двухсторонним обновлением данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141941/373567).

Comment: `x:Name` можно использовать только для связи между контролами в XAML, например вы в XAML можете привязываеться по имени контрола `{Binding Text, ElementName=MyTextBox}`, в таких случаях, когда вы остаетесь в рамках XAML, то использование `x:Name` оправдано, но следует избегать именования контролов, когда возможно, так как это создает сильные связи между ними и затруднит дальнейшее усовершенствавание UI приложения. В идеале, связи выполняются только относительные от дочернего контрола вверх по иерархии например `{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource, AncestorType=TextBox}}`

Comment: @aepot  спасибо. Обращу внимание.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118800/discussion-between-manul74-and-aepot).