# как экспортировать все данные из datagrid в excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagrid

Есть код который экспортирует данные в Excel, но проблема в том что он передает не все данные и программа выдает ошибку "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта"

```
private void toExcel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
            ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            ExcelApp.Cells[1, 1] = "Дата";
            ExcelApp.Cells[1, 2] = "Заряд";
            ExcelApp.Cells[1, 3] = "t1°";
            ExcelApp.Cells[1, 4] = "t2°";
            ExcelApp.Cells[1, 5] = "t3°";
            ExcelApp.Cells[1, 6] = "t4°";
            ExcelApp.Cells[1, 7] = "t5°";
            ExcelApp.Cells[1, 8] = "t6°";
            ExcelApp.Cells[1, 9] = "t7°";
            ExcelApp.Cells[1, 10] = "t8°";
            ExcelApp.Cells[1, 11] = "t9°";
            ExcelApp.Cells[1, 12] = "t10°";
            ExcelApp.Visible = true;

            for (int j = 0; j < TemperDataGrid.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < TemperDataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBlock text = TemperDataGrid.Columns[j].GetCellContent(TemperDataGrid.Items[i]) as TextBlock;
                    Excel.Range range = ExcelApp.Cells[i + 1, j + 1];
                    range.Value = text.Text; //здесь выходит ошибка
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Данные в Datagrid при прокручивании данные есть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но при экспорте в excel записываются только видимые значения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: Не все данные, это сколько?

Comment: @aepot в datagrid загружается до 1000 строк (в одной строке 12 столбцов), но при экспорте отображается только 13 (которые видны без прокручивания)

Comment: [Значение из строки n, столбца m DataGrid записать в переменную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141941/373567). Попробуйте работать с привязками и данными, а не насиловать ячейки `DataGrid` напрямую. Я понимаю, тема для вас новая, но вы все равно ее освоите, сейчас или потом, потому что без нее WPF - адские мучения. Работать с контролами в WPF из C# кода: 1) сложно, 2) не принято, не является нормальной практикой.

Comment: `но при экспорте отображается только 13 (которые видны без прокручивания)` это совершенно логично, потому что `DataGrid` оптимизирована и не грузит в себя лишние данные, которые на данный момент не требуется отображать. Если бы она создала вам сразу 12000 текстблоков, у вас бы хорошенько лагнул интерфейс, этак на секунду, а может больше.

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду биндинг до он есть, данные в datagrid заполняются с помощью List, проблема вот только в экспорте, но посмотрю привязки

Comment: Но вы работаете с ячейками таблицы, у вас так ничего не получится, работайте с данными, к которым таблица привязана вместо этого. Если вы прочитали мой ответ по ссылке, и у вас все сделано так, как я в том ответе описал, то показывайте ваши привязки.

Comment: Таже проблема.Почему-то выводит данные, которые видны, а ниже никак(вылазит ошибка и все)

Comment: @Maximus используйте данные которые вы ранее записывали в ListBox(ListView) и в цикле перебирайте все имеющиеся данные, в случае если в этих данные есть коллекция, то еще необходимо обращаться напрямую к элементу начиная с 0

Answer (score 1):

Как и сказал aepot стоило обращаться напрямую к данным

```
 private void toExcel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
            ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            for (int i = 0; i<stockList.Count; i++)
            {
                ExcelApp.Cells[i + 1, 1] = stockList[i].date;
                ExcelApp.Cells[i + 1, 2] = stockList[i].bat;
            }
            ExcelApp.Visible = true;
        }
```