# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку меня перебрасывало на новую TabItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Я делаю тест, в котором нужно составить вопросы.
Мне надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Дальше" меня перебрасывало на TabItem "Вопрос № 2".
Можно ли так сделать?
Код кнопки:

`<Button Content="Дальше" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="438,323,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" Height="55" Click="go_two"/>`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так добавьте обработчик события `Click` кнопки, там обратитесь к табконтролу, и задайте следующую табу активной.

Comment: Обработчик то я добавил, но какой код писать?

Comment: Важное замечание: ваш XAML выглядит, мягко говоря, ужасно. Это потому что вы позиционируете контролы в дизайнере, это не следует делать. XAML надо писать руками, а дизайнер это только чтобы посмотреть, что получилось, ну еще иногда перейти к нужному контролу в XAML просто тыкнув на него в дизайнере, но ни в коем не верстать интерфейс в дизайнере. Иначе вы не сможете собрать нормальный интерфейс.

Comment: По поводу, что писать в обработчике - у вас есть какое-то x:Name у таб-контрола. Вот к нему и обращайтесь `MyTabControl.SelectedIndex++`, где MyTabControl - имя табконтрола.

Comment: [Просто оставлю это здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1280658/373567)