# WPF Извлечение данных из DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

Дан DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="BasketGrid" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="20,292,0,0" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="16" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="150">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Код товара" Binding="{Binding i_d}" MaxWidth="0"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Binding="{Binding Ttl}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Количество" Binding="{Binding Quant}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Стоимость" Binding="{Binding Count}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Необходимо извлечь из него значения i_d и Quant. Как я могу это сделать?
Код ввода в таблицу:

```
 Goods selectedRow = GoodsGrid.SelectedItem as Goods;
        if (selectedRow != null)
        {
            int quantity;
            if (int.TryParse(Quan.Text, out quantity))
            {
                if (Quan.Text == "0")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Введите корректное количество необходимого товара.", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                }
                else if (decimal.Parse(Quan.Text) <= selectedRow.Quantity)
                {
                    int id = selectedRow.ID_Good;
                    double price = Convert.ToDouble(selectedRow.Price);
                    double total = price * quantity;
                    BasketGrid.Items.Add(new { i_d = id, Ttl = selectedRow.Title, Quant = quantity, Count = total });
```

Comment: В WPF не работают так с контролами, в WPF работают с данными. Чтобы достать данные, нужно знать, как вы их туда положили. `DataGrid` не хранит данные, она их только отображает.

Comment: Положил из другой таблицы, с ней проблем нет, она из SQL подгружается. Из того гайда какой именно код нужен - верхний или нижний?

Comment: Что? Вы в `ItemsSource` что положили, то оттуда и берите. Никуда данные ваши не убежали, лежат там где были. А лучше используйте привязки данных, ссылку на пример не игнорируйте, она выше.

Comment: У этого DataGrid'а нет своего ItemsSource, я полностью формирую его из другой таблицы.
По нажатию кнопки берутся данные из GoodsGrid, у которого ItemsSource - это SQL таблица Goods, привязанная через Entity Framework.

Comment: Не понимаю, о чем вы. Что помешало сохранить данные в коллекцию, например в список, а потом назначить ItemsSource?

Comment: В WPF люди стараются максимально отвязать данные от UI, ибо UI созданы **исключительно чтобы отображать**, а не хранить данные. Вот самое элементарное окну: `DataContext = this;`, там-же делаем свойство `pyblic List<Item> MyItems {get;}`, в XAML пишем `<DataGrid ItemsSource = "{Binding MyItems}"/>`, все, готово, у вас как видите UI в одном месте, данные в другом, и вы спокойно можете оперировать с данными в любой момент, не затрагивая UI. В вашем случае, вот этого вот `BasketGrid.Items.Add()` быть просто не должно, должно быть составление еще одного свойство с нужным типом.

Comment: Хорошо, как мне перестроить код добавления?

Comment: Аналогично кстати и `int.TryParse(Quan.Text, out quantity)` - это просто лишняя работа. Запомните просто одно простое правило - **UI не для хранения данных** и ему следуйте. Вот текстовое поле, аналогично `public int Value {get;set;}`, в XAML `<TextBox Text = "{Binding Value}"/>`, все, за вас автоматически WPF сконвертирует строку в число, и даже больше, если в текстовом поле не строка, он это поле выделит, и вам не надо будет делать эту проверку, выводить `MessageBox` с текстом `Введено неверное колличество.` и так далее. Ленитесь, как многие разработчике, делайте меньше)

Comment: К сожалению я мало понимаю в ваших словах, а диплом дописывать нужно, Может быть сможете скинуть какие-либо видеогайды или хотя бы текстовые?

Comment: `перестроить код добавления?` - зависит от того что там и как, предыдущий ваш вопрос я лично вообще не понял, там полная каша, с кучей лишнего, ужасным именованием (по типу `I_D`) b и так далее... Если по уму, то "выделенный объект" в данном случаи не подходит, вам нужны "кликабельные объекты", то есть, список кнопок, который будет привязан к одному методу, внутри которого и делаете `...Add(...)`, только делаете это не в контрол, а в привязанную коллекцию (если брать пример, что я сказал выше, то `MyItems.Add(new(...));`.

Comment: Во, нашел пример для WPF - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141941/373567 изучайте. Хотя, это на дубликат тянет даже. @EvgeniyZ что думете по этому поводу?

Comment: `я мало понимаю в ваших словах` - а вы раз попробуйте, поймите базовую механику привязок, а потом это говорите. Выше я вам пример базовой механики привязок дал, всего 3 строки кода, неужели это сложно? Да не поверю... Материалы - изучайте мои ответы, и aepot, много полезного найдете.

Comment: Я вам говорю ещё раз. Вы пытаетесь переписать мой диплом, который я пишу неделю на свой манер, скидывая кусочки кода. Это как утопающему кидать палки и кричать "Собирай плот!".

Comment: Решение по ссылке. Там есть и плот и палка, и как вам больше понравится.

Comment: Мы не пытаемся переписать на свой лад, мы просто говорим, что вы изначально делаете все не так, рано или поздно вам придется это принять (если конечно будет желание после учебы продолжить профессию). Решать вам, нужно это или нет, но хочу заметить, что ваши костыли, тут, на SO, мало кто будет решать, ибо повторю, предыдущий вопрос лично я вообще не понял, ибо это полнейшая каша. Нравится текущий уровень - дерзайте, без проблем, ну а если хотите по уму (а я если бы учился, то очень хотел), то советую прислушаться.

Comment: @aepot Да, хороший и простой пример, который показывает нужное. Как дубликат самое то, правда вон автор хочет "костыльный метод" )

Comment: @EvgeniyZ там в дубликате костыль тоже в наличии. ) Хочет ковырять View - пожалуйста.

Comment: @aepot И то верно, тогда можно смело закрывать)