# Вывод данных в Excel из DataGrid C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, entity-framework

Имеется проблема вывода данных в Excel из DataGrid.
Сам элемент определен так:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" x:Name="dgList" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

Чтобы его заполнить и вывести в Excel код реализован в кнопке:

```
        private void ExportCompButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (CompsList.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Сначала выберите соревнование, чтобы экпортировать данные");
                return;
            }
            int idSelectedEvent = (int)CompsList.SelectedItem.GetType().GetProperty("ID_Event").GetValue(CompsList.SelectedItem, null);
            dgList.ItemsSource = db.ResultReg.Where(rr => rr.RegEvent.ID_Event == idSelectedEvent && rr.RegEvent.RegStatus.RegStatusName != "Отклонена" && rr.RegEvent.RegStatus.RegStatusName != "На рассмотрении").Join(db.RegEvent,
            u => u.ID_RegEvent,
            c => c.ID_RegEvent,
            (u, c) => new
            {
                c.Event.NameEvent,
                c.User.LastName,
                c.User.FirstName,
                c.User.PatronymicName,
                u.TopEvent,
                u.UserScore,
                u.Descript
            }).ToList();
            dgList.Columns[0].Header = "Соревнование";
            dgList.Columns[1].Header = "Фамилия";
            dgList.Columns[2].Header = "Имя";
            dgList.Columns[3].Header = "Отчество";
            dgList.Columns[4].Header = "Место";
            dgList.Columns[5].Header = "Результат";
            dgList.Columns[6].Header = "Описание";
            dynamic Excel = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application"));
            var wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add();
            Excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
            var sheet1 = wb.Sheets[1];
            for (int j = 0; j < dgList.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet1.Cells[1, j + 1];
                sheet1.Cells[1, j + 1].Font.Bold = true;
                myRange.Value2 = dgList.Columns[j].Header;
                myRange.Interior.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbDarkGray;
                myRange.Font.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dgList.Columns.Count; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < dgList.Items.Count; j++)
                {
                    TextBlock b = dgList.Columns[i].GetCellContent(dgList.Items[j]) as TextBlock;
                    if (b == null)
                    {
                        b = new TextBlock();
                        b.Text = "-";
                    }
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet1.Cells[j + 2, i + 1];
                    myRange.Value2 = b.Text;
                    myRange.Columns.AutoFit();
                    myRange.Borders.LineStyle = 1;
                }
            Excel.Visible = true;
        }
```

В полях DataGrid могут быть пустые данные, но даже с поставленной проверкой это не работает. При экспорте, как я понимаю, данные в DataGrid заполняются, строчки он видит, но контент ячейки в DataGrid всегда null. Вот что выводит программа на данном этапе, однако, все поля должны были заполниться (я тестово добавил данные во все поля для проверки вывода)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как мне исправить эту ситуацию?

*Дополнение*

Дело в том, что идентичный код в другом месте выводит какие-никакие данные[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Только вот, если записей больше двух, которые ему нужно вывести, то он снова не видит контента[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код точно такой же, а результаты разные. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141941/373567 надо изначально с привязками данных работать, тогда и проблем таких не будет

Comment: Все та же проблема, создав класс под этот запрос все также ячейки DataGrid читаются как null

Comment: Вам не нужно читать DataGrid, вам нужно читать данные, которые вы положили в ItemsSource. Таблица - это не хранилище данных. Она только их показывает. Сами данные отдельно хранятся. Перечитайте ответ по ссылке. Ещё если вы изменили код, обновите код в вопросе.

Comment: Тогда не понимаю, не могли бы вы помочь? Что мне именно нужно изменить? Потому что я уже долго не могу понять проблему, а сроки уже поджимают

Comment: Я вам дал ссылку на готовый ответ с примерами. Писать дубликат ответа здесь не приветствуется. Попросил обновить код в вопросе, вы тоже не откликнулись.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых: Как написали в комментариях используйте Binding. То бишь привязку данных.
Во-вторых: Почитайте про Interaction.Triggers и выведите весь процесс из кода позади в вашу модель представления. Это позволит не дергать ваш datagrid и напрямую использовать коллекцию которая его заполняет в модели представления