# Как изменить значение конкретной ячейки DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Есть DataGrid, предположим, с двумя столбцами и двумя строками. Как изменить ячейку первой строки второго столбца? Почему-то здесь нет Rows и Cells как в DataGridView

Comment: Используйте привязки данных https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141941/373567